# Java Object Oriented Programming Object Scope

Tags: java, oop, scope

Okay, so far I know a lot about java. Databases, URL, SQL, etc. But so far my books and I have only dealt with single class programs. I was wondering something about OOP.

If I have a class that defines an example object and each example object has it's own array.

Ex.

```
public class Example {
Array exampleArray;
}
```

does that mean that every 'example' object has it's own unique 'exampleArray' Array object that can be referenced by "insert objectname here".exampleArray ?

Ex.

```
Example dataBase = new Example();
int length = dataBase.exampleArray.length();
```

will this work?

sorry, for some reason the line feed isn't working with my example code

Comment: Why don't you try? How could you test your assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each `Example` object will have its own unique `exampleArray` array object.  Typically you would make it a `private` member variable and access it through methods, though, instead of allowing clients to access the array directly.

Comment: whew, this makes things so much easier. Java books really only focus on one class programs, not large scale data management :/

Comment: @user1827733 If you're using an introductory book on Java, most of the examples probably are going to use a single class to illustrate a point.  A good book on data structures with Java examples will give you a taste of OOP and larger-scale data management. For example: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/

Answer (score 0):

Each object that is generated will have it's own set of attributes.  So the following code produces two unique objects:

```
Example first = new Example();  
Example second = new Example();
```

with unique attributes for each of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, you will get a `NullPointerException` because you never assigned a **value** to exampleArray in your class. But in general, yes, each *instance* of `Example` has its own unique array.

Comment: Thank you, I know I would get a Null Pointer, but I put the bare minimum code to get my point across.

Comment: If you say something doesn't work without providing details and claim to know 'a lot' about a language without understanding object's properties, it's understandable we start at the high level, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit off topic but I feel worth mentioning. If you intend to make a copy of a Object, you need to be careful that you make a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy). Doing so will cause each to act as though they were instantiated normally. If you don't, they will "share" the attribute.

Comment: You mean `copy of an object` not class.